# Example which proves independence of Kuratowski's fourth closure axiom

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity, pointwise-convergence

In his first volume of Topology, Kuratowski mentions an example which shows that his fourth axiom, $\overline{\overline{A}} = \overline{A}$, is independent from the other three of the closure operator. Take $X$ the set of all functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and for $A \subseteq X$ define $\overline{A}$ as all functions obtained as pointwise limits of sequences of functions in $A$. Then, if $A$ is the continous functions, he claims that the Dirichlet function $f$ with $1$ on rationals and $0$ on irrationals is in $\overline{\overline{A}}$ but not in $\overline{A}$.

To show that $f \in \overline{\overline{A}}$, I noted that for any finite set of rationals, we can find $(g_n)_n$ a sequence of continous functions which converges to $0$ outside that set and $1$ on those rationals, by patching together different pieces of graphs of $a_nx^n$ and $1/(b_nx^n)$; this shows that $\overline{A}$ contains a function which is $1$ on any given *finite* set of rationals and $0$ outside. So by using a bijection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (like the diagonal one), we can choose these finite sets of rationals to be in a sequence which is $\mathbb{Q}$ in the limit, hence we have a sequence of functions in $\overline{A}$ which converges to $f$. Is this correct?

For $f \not\in \overline{A}$, I'd have to show that the pointwise limit of a continous sequence of functions cannot be everywhere discontinous (my intuition says it can probably only be discontinous on a Lebesgue negligible set), as suggested by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265199/dirichlet-function-pointwise-convergence) question. I can't think of how to prove this; can anyone provide the proof/a sketch of it/a resource where it is found?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Of course, if all you want is to prove the independence of the fourth axiom, you can do it with a trivial example like $X=\mathbb N$, $\overline A=A\cup\{x+1:x\in A\}$. But Kuratowski chose to give a natural example which is interesting for its own sake.

Comment: In case you're interested about generalized topological spaces satisfying the first three axioms (but not necessarily satisfying the fourth axiom), see the sections titled *6. Čech Closure Operators* and *7. Topological Closure Operators* in my answers to [General topological space with closure operation as in Russian translation of Hausdorff's 1914 and 1927 Mengenlehre](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume for a contradiction that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to the Dirichlet function $f$.

For $N\in\mathbb N$ let $S_N=\{x\in\mathbb R:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le\frac13\text{ for all }n\ge N\}$.

Since $f_n\to f$ pointwise, $\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty S_N=\mathbb R$. By the Baire category theorem, not all of the sets $S_N$ are nowhere dense. Choose $N$ so that the set $S_N$ is dense in some interval $(a,b)$. Choose $c,d$ so that $a\lt c\lt d\lt b$, $f(c)=0$, $f(d)=1$. Choose $n\ge N$ so that $f_n(c)\lt\frac12\lt f_n(d)$.

Since $n\ge N$, we have $f_n(x)\notin(\frac13,\frac23)$ for $x\in S_N$. Since $S_N$ is dense in $(c,d)$, and since $f_n$ is continuous, we have $f_n(x)\notin(\frac13,\frac23)$, and in particular $f_n(x)\ne\frac12$, for $x\in(c,d)$, but this contradicts the intermediate value theorem.